# Docker EE on Windows Server 2016 fails to install

Tags: docker, windows-server

Under `Windows Server 2016`, first, I was directed to do this:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator>  [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Then, following instructions from [here](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/install/windows/docker-ee/) I type:

```
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

which runs fine. However, when I try:

```
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
WARNING: Cannot find path
'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json' because it does not
exist.
WARNING: The property 'Content' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Docker'. Try
Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Not sure what to do next. I have tried to search on this error, but no help?

**EDIT 1**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> fsutil 8dot3name query C:
The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).

Based on the above two settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on C:
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: That `ADMIN~1` makes me wonder if the state of 8dot3name creation been changed. `fsutil 8dot3name query C:` at a cmd/PS prompt will tell you its current state.

Comment: See Edit 1 for the output of this command

Comment: Does it work if you open "Windows PowerShell (Admin)", rather than just being logged in as Administrator? (Start again from the beginning.)